# Range-v3: Use view_facade to provide both const and non-const iterators

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am having trouble using view_facade (from [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)) to create a view that provides both const and non-const access. As an example, I tried modifying the view_facade test (in test/view_facade.cpp) to allow non-const access (by default it only allows const access):

```
struct MyRange
  : ranges::range_facade<MyRange>
{
private:
    friend struct ranges::range_access;
    std::vector<int> ints_;

    template <bool isConst>
    struct cursor
    {
    private:
        using It = typename std::conditional<isConst, std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>::type;
        using RefType = typename std::conditional<isConst, int const&, int&>::type;
        It iter;
    public:
        cursor() = default;
        cursor(It it)
          : iter(it)
        {}
        RefType current() const
        {
            return *iter;
        }
    //...
    };
/*    // Uncommenting these overloads will cause an error, below.
    cursor<true> begin_cursor() const
    {
        return {ints_.begin()};
    }
    cursor<true> end_cursor() const
    {
        return {ints_.end()};
    }
*/
    cursor<false> begin_cursor()
    {
        return {ints_.begin()};
    }
    cursor<false> end_cursor()
    {
        return {ints_.end()};
    }
public:
    MyRange()
      : ints_{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    {}
};

int main() {
    MyRange nc;
    int& nci = *nc.begin();  // error here when const overloads present.
}
```

[Full code here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/879f4ab3340b5ce6)

This works fine with the const overloads of begin_cursor and end_cursor commented out. However, if I add those overloads back in, the following error is generated on the indicated line (GCC 5.1):

```
error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&' discards qualifiers
```

It seems to be selecting the const version, giving me a const iterator. What I want is: const iterators for const objects, and non-const iterators for non-const objects. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`view_facade` is for building views. Views refer to data they don't own. They are like pointers in that logically they are indirections. And like pointers, top-level `const` *should* have no effect on the `const`-ness of the data referenced. That is whether you dereference an `int*` or an `int*const`, the result is the same: `int&`.

Your view is not a view. It owns its data. (See the `vector<int> ints_` data member.) Trying to use `view_facade` to turn this data structure into a view is bound to lead to frustration. This is very much by design. Views are distinct from containers. The Range-v3 library doesn't come with a container facade, sorry.

(What's going on: since views represent indirection, `view_facade` tries very hard to make const and non-const `begin()` and `end()` return the same types. If `cursor_begin() const` is present, that one is *always* chosen. Always. When this breaks code, it's generally because that code is confusing containers with views.)

Comment: I guess I didn't understand what was meant by a view not owning its data. The example I posted was pretty much straight out of the tests, but what I was actually trying to do was wrap a pointer + size in a range-like interface. Since the view wouldn't own the pointer in the sense of allocating/deallocating the data (it's managed by a third-party library), I thought a view_facade was appropriate. But, your explanation makes sense. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A pointer/length pair *is* a view. `view::counted` is precisely that. If you replace your `vector` member with pointer/length, things should work much better.

Comment: Ah! `view::counted` is a perfect example. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: "When this breaks code, it's generally because that code is..." already broken.

Comment: Although container adaptors *are* interesting and useful (see `std::stack` for instance), I'm not sure this is the right time to further expand the scope of range-v3. I hope to spend more of my time polishing and proposing what's already there, and less time adding new features that I'll need to maintain.

Comment: Agreed! Just thought it'd be impolite not to offer. Thanks for your time.